# Play 2.4 java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have an application. On application start I wake up my akka actor every 24 second. Actor iterates through some entities within JPA.withTransaction, do some job and sends email to my users.

The problem is within JPA.withTransaction method when calling render method (using to render scala template) as runtime exception is thrown: There is no Htto Context available from here

```
    [error] - akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy - JPA transaction failed
11:50:42 worker.1   |  java.lang.RuntimeException: JPA transaction failed
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:107) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:148) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at utils.MedicalValidityActor.onReceive(MedicalValidityActor.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:57) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.mvc.Http$Context$Implicit.ctx(Http.java:308) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$.requestHeader(TemplateMagicForJava.scala:58) ~[play-java_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at views.html.emailTemplateMedicalValidity_Scope0$emailTemplateMedicalValidity.apply(emailTemplateMedicalValidity.template.scala:77) ~[classes/:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at views.html.emailTemplateMedicalValidity_Scope0$emailTemplateMedicalValidity.render(emailTemplateMedicalValidity.template.scala:113) ~[classes/:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at views.html.emailTemplateMedicalValidity.render(emailTemplateMedicalValidity.template.scala) ~[classes/:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at utils.MedicalValidityActor$1.invoke(MedicalValidityActor.java:97) ~[classes/:na]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$1(DefaultJPAApi.java:103) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:136) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:102) ~[play-java-jpa_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
11:50:42 worker.1   |   ... 14 common frames omitted
```

This is my code:

```
public class MedicalValidityActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Inject
    HttpExecutionContext ec;

    @Transactional
    public void onReceive(Object message) {
        if (message instanceof CheckMedicalValidity) {
            // START

            JPA.withTransaction(new play.libs.F.Callback0() {
                @Override
                public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                    //Get today and add one month
                    Date todayPlusMonth = new Date();
                    todayPlusMonth = DateUtils.addMonths(todayPlusMonth, 1);

                    List<Organization> organizationList = Organization.findAll();

                    for(Organization organization : organizationList){
                        List<Player> playerList =  PlayerManager.findAllActiveDomesticPlayersByOrganization(organization);

                        // List containing all players for specific organization that have invalid medical
                        ArrayList<Player> playersInvalidMedical = new ArrayList<>();

                        for(Player player : playerList){

                            System.out.println(organization.getName() + " " +  player.getFirstName() + " " + player.getLastName() + " " + player.getMedicalValidityFormatted());

                            if(player.getMedicalValidity() != null && !player.isMedicalValid()) {

                                // Medical is not valid anymore
                                playersInvalidMedical.add(player);

                            } else if(player.getMedicalValidity() != null && todayPlusMonth.after(player.getMedicalValidity())) {

                                // Medical is not valid anymore
                                playersInvalidMedical.add(player);

                                player.setMedicalValid(false);
                            }
                        }

                        // send notification to users about medical validity

                        if(!playersInvalidMedical.isEmpty()) {

                            System.out.println("Potekli:  " + playersInvalidMedical.size());

                            // Get recipients by organization
                            List<EndUser> endUsers = EndUserManager.findByOrganization(organization);

                            ArrayList<String> recipients = new ArrayList<>();

                            for(EndUser enduser : endUsers){
                                if(enduser.getRoles().get(0).getName().equals(SecurityRole.ADMINISTRATOR) ||
                                        enduser.getRoles().get(0).getName().equals(SecurityRole.SECRETARY) ||
                                        enduser.getRoles().get(0).getName().equals(SecurityRole.COACH) ||
                                        enduser.getRoles().get(0).getName().equals(SecurityRole.HEAD)) {

                                    // add recipients
                                    recipients.add(enduser.getEmail());
                                }
                            }

                            System.out.println("1");

                            // Initialize now so it is not initialized every iteration
                            EmailUtilsMailGun mailGunUtils = new EmailUtilsMailGun();

                            System.out.println("2");

                           String emailTemplate = emailTemplateMedicalValidity.render(organization, playersInvalidMedical).toString();

                            System.out.println("3");

                            mailGunUtils.sendEmailToWithoutAttachmenet(emailTemplate, organization.getName(), organization.getEmail(),
                                    "Potekli Zdravniški Pregledi", recipients);

                            System.out.println("4");

                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```